# array of 2 part arrays, can I get array[i][1] when array[i][0] is equal to a particular condition? (i in range 0 - array.length-1)

Tags: javascript, arrays

first time posting here... Question - I have an array consisting of two parts per entry (time, conversion rate) when my time value I'm checking against is between array[i][0] and array[i+1][0], I want to get array[i][1] when this occurs however i get an error saying

```
if ((transactionInfo.blockTime >= Number(data[i][0])) && (transactionInfo.blockTime < data[i+1][0])){ 
                                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"
```

if anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it! Many thanks

```js
function convertionfinder(transactionInfo, saleAmount) {
  for (let i of data) {
    if ((transactionInfo.blockTime >= Number(data[i][0])) &&
      (transactionInfo.blockTime < data[i + 1][0])) {
      let converted_val = saleAmount * data[i][1];
      console.log(converted_val);
      return converted_val
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script>
var data = `1644451200,113.96000000
1644447600,114.97000000
1644444000,114.50000000
1644440400,115.79000000
1644436800,115.07000000
1644433200,114.07000000
1644429600,114.35000000
1644426000,114.59000000
1644422400,113.18000000
1644418800,114.16000000
1644415200,114.29000000
1644411600,114.69000000
1644408000,113.27000000
1644404400,113.42000000
1644400800,111.14000000
1644397200,110.99000000
1644393600,111.50000000
1644390000,111.34000000
1644386400,110.48000000
1644382800,111.29000000
1644379200,111.23000000
1644375600,111.65000000
1644372000,113.34000000
1644368400,114.91000000
1644364800,113.44000000
1644361200,113.09000000
1644357600,112.75000000
1644354000,113.27000000
1644350400,110.84000000
1644346800,111.56000000
1644343200,111.47000000
1644339600,111.08000000
1644336000,112.07000000
1644332400,112.24000000
1644328800,112.59000000
1644325200,112.54000000
1644321600,114.32000000
1644318000,113.50000000
1644314400,114.03000000
1644310800,114.22000000
1644307200,117.70000000
1644303600,118.10000000
1644300000,118.84000000
1644296400,118.23000000
1644292800,117.48000000
1644289200,116.93000000
1644285600,118.71000000
1644282000,117.02000000
1644278400,117.57000000
1644274800,118.09000000
1644271200,117.97000000
1644267600,118.74000000
1644264000,120.04000000
1644260400,119.74000000
1644256800,120.92000000
1644253200,120.29000000
1644249600,121.31000000
1644246000,120.89000000
1644242400,118.59000000
1644238800,117.35000000
1644235200,117.50000000
1644231600,116.91000000
1644228000,116.39000000
1644224400,117.07000000
1644220800,117.29000000
1644217200,118.44000000
1644213600,118.16000000
1644210000,118.98000000
1644206400,119.21000000
1644202800,114.93000000
1644199200,113.83000000
1644195600,113.71000000
1644192000,115.26000000
1644188400,112.78000000
1644184800,112.84000000
1644181200,112.54000000
1644177600,112.88000000
1644174000,112.28000000
1644170400,113.75000000
1644166800,113.69000000
1644163200,113.06000000
1644159600,112.90000000
1644156000,114.37000000
1644152400,114.41000000
1644148800,114.41000000
1644145200,114.63000000
1644141600,115.56000000
1644138000,114.55000000
1644134400,114.31000000
1644130800,112.73000000
1644127200,113.35000000
1644123600,113.79000000
1644120000,114.41000000
1644116400,114.54000000
1644112800,115.38000000
1644109200,114.20000000
1644105600,113.74000000
1644102000,114.76000000
1644098400,113.98000000
1644094800,114.17000000
1644091200,113.49000000
1644087600,113.38000000
1644084000,114.12000000
1644080400,112.69000000
1644076800,116.01000000
1644073200,115.19000000
1644069600,115.20000000
1644066000,114.35000000
1644062400,114.95000000
1644058800,115.25000000
1644055200,115.60000000
1644051600,115.95000000
1644048000,115.56000000
1644044400,116.86000000
1644040800,116.44000000
1644037200,115.86000000
1644033600,114.02000000
1644030000,111.34000000
1644026400,110.77000000
1644022800,111.31000000
1644019200,112.63000000
1644015600,109.98000000
1644012000,110.92000000
1644008400,110.51000000
1644004800,110.64000000
1644001200,109.38000000
1643997600,109.63000000
1643994000,109.75000000
1643990400,107.19000000
1643986800,103.80000000
1643983200,102.60000000
1643979600,104.16000000
1643976000,104.80000000
1643972400,105.49000000
1643968800,106.13000000
1643965200,106.03000000
1643961600,104.90000000
1643958000,106.19000000
1643954400,104.93000000
1643950800,102.53000000
1643947200,102.39000000
1643943600,102.59000000
1643940000,100.95000000
1643936400,101.36000000
1643932800,101.83000000
1643929200,100.60000000
1643925600,100.64000000
1643922000,96.67000000
1643918400,96.80000000
1643914800,97.52000000
1643911200,97.89000000
1643907600,97.07000000
1643904000,98.25000000
1643900400,96.73000000
1643896800,96.28000000
1643893200,96.80000000
1643889600,97.43000000
1643886000,94.58000000
1643882400,95.04000000
1643878800,98.92000000
1643875200,99.40000000
1643871600,98.18000000
1643868000,98.84000000
1643864400,98.08000000
1643860800,97.38000000
1643857200,99.93000000
1643853600,99.21000000
1643850000,101.20000000
1643846400,101.91000000
1643842800,101.19000000
1643839200,100.36000000
1643835600,104.22000000
1643832000,110.02000000
1643828400,109.68000000
1643824800,105.97000000
1643821200,105.48000000
1643817600,105.95000000
1643814000,105.92000000
1643810400,109.19000000
1643806800,111.64000000
1643803200,110.01000000
1643799600,109.98000000
1643796000,110.52000000
1643792400,109.30000000
1643788800,108.52000000
1643785200,108.90000000
1643781600,109.71000000
1643778000,109.19000000
1643774400,110.62000000
1643770800,109.64000000
1643767200,108.66000000
1643763600,109.90000000
1643760000,109.99000000
1643756400,109.89000000
1643752800,111.74000000
1643749200,109.99000000
1643745600,107.87000000
1643742000,111.51000000
1643738400,111.56000000
1643734800,112.98000000
1643731200,108.70000000
1643727600,108.05000000
1643724000,107.99000000
1643720400,107.11000000
1643716800,106.35000000
1643713200,106.11000000
1643709600,104.56000000
1643706000,107.44000000
1643702400,105.41000000
1643698800,104.98000000
1643695200,105.04000000
1643691600,106.08000000
1643688000,106.92000000
1643684400,102.38000000
1643680800,102.05000000
1643677200,100.42000000
1643673600,99.50000000
1643670000,99.89000000
1643666400,99.33000000
1643662800,98.19000000
1643659200,98.40000000
1643655600,97.70000000
1643652000,97.64000000
1643648400,97.83000000
1643644800,95.42000000
1643641200,92.50000000
1643637600,91.93000000
1643634000,91.08000000
1643630400,91.36000000
1643626800,91.47000000
1643623200,90.86000000
1643619600,90.28000000
1643616000,90.26000000
1643612400,89.91000000
1643608800,90.27000000
1643605200,89.87000000
1643601600,90.73000000
1643598000,90.85000000
1643594400,90.23000000`
    .toString() // convert Buffer to string
    .split('\n') // split string to lines
    .map(e => e.trim()) // remove white spaces for each line
    .map(e => e.split(',').map(e => e.trim())); // split each line to array
</script>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Please add the relevant object to run a [mcve]

Comment: not 100% sure how to do it as i'm parsing it in from a csv file to create the array

Comment: Please post the relavent test data to reproduce the issue

Comment: Now please add the relevant `convertionfinder(data,???)`

Comment: What is   transactionInfo.blockTime ??? And why not `for (let i =0; i< data.length-1;i++) {` if you are looking at i+1